# How to ensure local filesystems are mounted before NFS server starts?

Tags: nfs

I have a simple Ubuntu 20.04 home server sharing a directory by NFS.  The directory being shared is contained on a local filesystem, but not the root filesystem.  Sometimes on boot the NFS server starts before the mount is ready, and so the NFS server errors out.  I need to login and restart the NFS server (`sudo systemctl restart nfs-server.service`), or reboot and get lucky.

Is threre a way to ensure that the NFS server starts only once this filesystem is ready?

---

The error from the NFS server is like this:

```
$ systemctl status nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-05-19 11:16:34 BST; 3h 10min ago
    Process: 927 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 931 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 932 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 19 11:16:34 box systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
May 19 11:16:34 box exportfs[927]: exportfs: /etc/exports [2]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "*:/storage/Shared".
May 19 11:16:34 box exportfs[927]:   Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
May 19 11:16:34 box exportfs[927]:   NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x
May 19 11:16:34 box exportfs[927]: exportfs: Failed to stat /storage/Shared: No such file or directory
May 19 11:16:34 box systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 19 11:16:34 box systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 19 11:16:34 box systemd[1]: Stopped NFS server and services.
```

The `/etc/fstab` line looks like so:

```
UUID=<blah>   /storage   btrfs   nofail,subvol=@storage,compress-force=zstd   0       0
```

The `/etc/exports` like like so:

```
/storage/Shared    *(ro,insecure,all_squash)
```

Comment: I think it *should* be possible to make the nfs-service start after the local mount as outlined here (this was for a network mount, but the principle is the same) [Set systemd service to execute after fstab mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247547/65304)

Comment: Use `After=network.target` in the unit.

Comment: @steeldriver - Any chance you can enter your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Rinzwind - Any chance you can enter your comment as an answer?

Comment: @pauldoo I was hoping you'd get it to work based on the info in the linked U&L answer, and then write an answer of your own here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the tips in the comments from @steeldriver and @Rinzwind, I managed to get this working.

First, determine the name of the systemd unit that is generated for the mount point (in my case `/storage`):

```
$ systemctl list-units | grep '/storage' | grep 'mount'
  storage-.snapshots.mount      loaded active mounted   /storage/.snapshots                                                          
  storage.mount                 loaded active mounted   /storage
```

Then, following [these docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Modify) on how to modify an existing unit file, I added the new `After=` tweak for `nfs-server.service`:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/nfs-server.service.d/custom.conf 
[Unit]
After=storage.mount
```

Next, apply the changes and restart `nfs-server` to confirm that the new config is picked up (note that `custom.conf` is listed):

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart nfs-server.service
$ systemctl status nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nfs-server.service.d
             └─custom.conf
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-05-24 20:52:08 BST; 6s ago
    Process: 20384 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 20385 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 20385 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 24 20:52:07 box systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
May 24 20:52:07 box exportfs[20384]: exportfs: /etc/exports [2]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "*:/storage/Shared".
May 24 20:52:07 box exportfs[20384]:   Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
May 24 20:52:07 box exportfs[20384]:   NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x
May 24 20:52:08 box systemd[1]: Finished NFS server and services.
```

Lastly, reboot, and bask in a NFS server that was started after the mount point was available.